# Saber a cor do Button Android Studio (Java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-activity, button

Boa tarde, preciso saber ler a cor do Button e armazenar em uma váriavel no java para plataforma Android porém está apresentando erros, podem me ajudar ? Segue abaixo meu código:

```
private EditText cor;
public Button coreshexa;


coreshexa = (Button) findViewById( R.id.btn1);
cor = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.txtviewcorcateg);
ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable) coreshexa.getBackground();
cor.setText((CharSequence) buttonColor);
```

Comment: Qual erro que tá dando? e passe mais informações do código, vc tá inicializando as variáveis em qual método?

Comment: Quando clico no botão para ler o background do botão ele diz que a aplicação parou, apenas esse comando está apresentando erro na aplicação, a ideia é fazer uma paleta de cores com botões e ler o hexadecimal do botão escolhido

Comment: Ola Matheus, conseguiu resolver pela minha resposta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pelo seu exemplo faça o seguinte:

```
ColorDrawable buttonColor = (ColorDrawable) coreshexa.getBackground();

//recupera a cor do botão como inteiro
int colorInt = buttonColor.getColor();

//transforma o inteiro da cor em hexadecimal
String colorHex = Integer.toHexString(colorInt);

cor.setText(colorHex);
```

Caso queira utilizar a cor do botão em outro botão:

```
//se for usar em Hex:
coreshexa.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#"+colorHex));
//se for usar em int:
coreshexa.setBackgroundColor(colorInt);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado Murilo, desculpe a demora para dar um retorno mas seu código meu ajudou muito, agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro, Se a resposta te ajudou, por favor marque-a como respondida e/ou como útil.